# How to use Memcached Enyim

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, memcached

I created an instant amazon EC2 with a security group. after I created a Neaud to a level ElastiCache binds to the security group. on my local machines I can connect to EC2 via the I Remote Desktop Connection. but I can not be doing operations add, get in my client EnyimMemcached (vb net  dot net) I do not know what to thank you for your help

code vb net:

```vb
Dim client As New MemcachedClient()
        'methode  added Key,Value
        Dim bit As Boolean = client.Store(Memcached.StoreMode.Add, "ValueKey", "ValueOfValue")
        Dim bit1 As Boolean = client.Store(Memcached.StoreMode.Set, "ValueKey011", "ValueOfValue0001")
        'Methode Get Value Key,Value
        Dim ValueByValue As String = client.Get("ValueKey")
        'Methode  Update Value For ValueKey
        '  client.Store(Memcached.StoreMode.Replace, "ValueKey", "ValueOfValue001")
        ' Methode Remove By ValueKey
        client.Remove("ValueKey")
```

and App.config:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <section name="memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection, Enyim.Caching" />
    </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
      <startup> 
          <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
      </startup>
    <enyim.com>
      <memcached>
        <servers>
          <!-- put your own server(s) here-->
          <add address="Adressssssss01" port="11211" />
        </servers>
        <socketPool minPoolSize="100" maxPoolSize="1000" connectionTimeout="00:10:10" deadTimeout="00:02:00" />
      </memcached>
    </enyim.com>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: How are you trying to add? Any code?

Comment: In vb net 
 Dim client As New MemcachedClient()
        'methode  added Key,Value
        Dim bit As Boolean = client.Store(Memcached.StoreMode.Add, "ValueKey", "ValueOfValue")
        Dim bit1 As Boolean = client.Store(Memcached.StoreMode.Set, "ValueKey011", "ValueOfValue0001")
        'Methode Get Value Key,Value
        Dim ValueByValue As String = client.Get("ValueKey")
        'Methode  Update Value For ValueKey
        '  client.Store(Memcached.StoreMode.Replace, "ValueKey", "ValueOfValue001")
        ' Methode Remove By ValueKey
        client.Remove("ValueKey")
and file config: